# Setting responsive background image to Div

Tags: css, magento, background-image, newsletter

I want a background image (responsive) to my newsletterbox

So I added in CSS:

```
background-image: url(../images/newsletterbox.png);
width:100%;
height:auto;
```

The img is 280px by 250px, but I want the img at fullsize ( and responsive) with the Div inside, not just a bar.

Please take a look at [the website](http://www.10past10.com)

How can I show an responsive background img (full size) with the DIV (newsletter box) inside?

Thanks!